# Why does this matrix belongs to $U(m+n)/[U(m)\times U(n)]$?

Tags: group-theory, topological-order

$Q(k)=U(k)\Lambda U ^{\dagger}(k)$ where $U(k)\in U(n+m)$ and $\Lambda=\
 \begin{pmatrix}
  I_{m} & 0 \\
  0 & -I_{n}  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$

So we have $Q(k)\in G_{m,n+m}(\mathbf C)=U(m+n)/[U(m)\times U(n)]$ $G$ is Grasmannian.

This capture is the reasoning behind this calculation.

[image: [Ludwig]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu4zr.jpg)

But I don't get this.

Comment: Could you perhaps try to ask a more specific question than "I don't get this"? Also, please *type out* material you want to cite in your question since images cannot be searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if

$$U =\begin{pmatrix}
U_{m} & 0 \\ 0 & U_n
\end{pmatrix}\qquad  $$

then

$$ U \Lambda U^\dagger = \Lambda \,. $$

It appears at first glance that the matrix $Q$ is specified by an element $U$ of $\mathrm{U}(m+n)$. However, there is a subgroup of these matrices consisting of elements of the above form, isomorphic to $\mathrm{U}(n) \times \mathrm{U}(m)$, which only gives rise to a single $Q$.

More generally, for a given element $M$ of $\mathrm{U}(n+m)$, all elements of the form $MU$ where $U$ is as above give rise to the same $Q$ (check this). Hence it is in fact the *cosets* of $\mathrm{U}(n)\times\mathrm{U}(m)$ that correspond to distinct matrices $Q$. The set of such cosets is denoted

$$ \mathrm{U}(m+n)/(\mathrm{U}(m) \times \mathrm{U}(n)) \,.$$

---

More geometrically, if one starts with the Grassmannian manifold $G$, the space of $m$-dimensional planes in an $(m+n)$-dimensional complex vector space, one can note the following:

1. $\mathrm{U}(m+n)$, which acts on $\mathbb{C}^{m+n}$, induces a transitive group action on $G$.
2. The isotropy group of a given plane consists of transformations which mix up only the $m$ basis vectors within the plane and those which mix up only the $n$ basis vectors in the complement to the plane. This group is thus $\mathrm{U}(m) \times \mathrm{U}(n)$.
3. It is known that if a Lie group $G$ acts transitively on a smooth manifold $M$ with isotropy group $H$ then $M \cong G/H$ (this is a manifold quotient, not a group quotient).

For more general information, see [homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space) and [symmetric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space).

Comment: About the first point of view I have some parts not clear for me.  I get that if $U(k)\in U(m)\times U(n)$ than we get $Q(k)$ is constant for $k$. So in order to prevent this $ U(k)$ should be something rather than $ U(m)\times U(n)$.
So if we impose that constraint does it mean that $Q \in U(m+n)/[U(m) \times U(n)]$.
If this is the case I don't understand how that condition of $U(k)$ makes this implication of $Q$. Because quotient groups as far as I understand is just writing the group in modular of the divisor.

Comment: It's not so much that we need to 'prevent' anything, but rather that all $\mathrm{U}(m) \times \mathrm{U}(n)$ elements give rise to the same $Q$. Taking a quotient simply means identifying all such elements as a single object, which is appropriate since they indeed all correspond to $\Lambda$. Note that this is not a quotient group, but rather a quotient manifold, though this is perhaps besides the point.

Comment: Yes, that's a good analogy. If we only care about the value of $\sin(x)$ and not $x$ itself, we can *identify* elements $x$ and $x + 2 \pi n$ for any integer $n$. You have to be a bit careful in this particular case, however, since even for $x$ in the interval $[0, 2 \pi)$ there are two values of $x$ that yield each possible value of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Okay so as an analogy $sin(x)$ is same with $sin(x+n2\pi)$ so $x mod 2 \pi$ will give all distinct results. 
So in this case, $Q$ is same for every $U$ with above form, in $MU$ so we need to consider distinct $MU$. So it is like U implies distinct Q, when for $mod U(m) \times U(n)$.which is a coset.
So only certain $U$ gives distinct $Q$ so the set of these distinct $Q$ are $U(m+n)/U(m)\times U(n)$.

Comment: Yes I think that's right. But again, be careful about how far you push your $\sin(x)$ analogy, since *not* all $x \mod 2 \pi$ give distinct results.

Comment: but, in that $sin(x)$ example $x$ can be any real number. not only $mod 2 \pi$. 
but in our case, it looks like we only consider $mod U(m) \times U(n)$. I mean is $Q$ can not be any matrix from $U(n+m)$. When we write $Q$ as above form does it mean that it can be only some specific elements of $U(m+n)$ And these are cosets?

Comment: Yes, $x$ can be any real number. But if all we care about is the value of $\sin(x)$, then since $\{0,2\pi, 4\pi,6\pi,...\}$ all yield the same value of $\sin(x)$ we can identify them as a single entity. This is a *coset*. Likewise the set $\{1, 1+2\pi, 1+4\pi,...\}$ is also a coset. In the case posted in the question, we don't care about $U$ but only about $Q = U\Lambda U^\dagger$. So we should group together all elements of $\mathrm{U}(m+n)$ that give rise to a particular matrix $Q$, and treat them as one entity.